# Alternatives to QuickTime 7 for making simple edits without re-encoding?

Tags: quicktime, catalina

*(This is similar to [a question I asked in 2014](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117306/what-options-are-available-to-losslessly-trim-mp4-m4v-video-on-10-8-or-above) but I'm hoping there are better options available now, plus we have to take the lack of 32-bit apps into consideration now.)*

QuickTime 7 will no longer work in macOS 15 "Catalina" so the time has come to find an alternative.

*Playback* is no problem, as there are many apps that can playback videos in more formats than QuickTime 7 could.

However, one of the best features of QuickTime 7 "Pro" was that it was able to **make simple edits to video files** (not just trimming from the start or end, which is all QuickTime X can do).

It also did so without re-encoding the videos, at least for .mov files.

I'm hoping to find *GUI* app options, rather than, say, some kind of magical `ffmpeg` invocation. Bonus points for being easy to use and not having an atrocious UI, but at this point I'm open to just about anything.

Answer (score 2):

QuickTime X seems to be able to open a `.mp4` file, trim it, and re-save as `.mp4` with no re-encoding.

This was surprising to me, as the only way to `Export` the file is via a filetype change to `.mov`.

If you take other actions such as `Add Clip to End...`, the menu item for `Save` will become greyed out and you will be forced to export as `.mov` if you wish to save. If you `Split Clip` more than one time without deleting a segment it similarly prevents the save.

But this does enable easy trimming and re-saving without `.mov` conversion using Quicktime X.

#### Trim .mp4 video file:

1. Open a `.mp4` with QuickTime Player X
2. Scrub to a location in the file. Use the keyboard arrow controls for frame-perfect accuracy.
3. Press `Split Clip` <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to cut the video into two segments.
4. Select the unwanted segment. Press <kbd>delete</kbd> to delete.

Note: You can also use the `Trim` <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> command. But I find it is almost impossible to accurately set the In/Out markers without keyboard arrow controls, which do not function in the Trim UI. Instead, use `Split Clip` to delete each end of the trim.

#### Save without re-encoding

1. Press `Save` <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
2. A "Save As..." dialog will pop up.
3. Note that it is exporting as `.mp4`. Default value: `Export As: Untitled.mp4`
4. Rename your file and save.
5. Resulting format will be same file type and dimensions as your source file. Its file size should also be smaller, depending on how much was trimmed.

[image: Export As:]

#### Export As...

Note that the `Export As...` menu does **NOT** contain "pass through" or "original" or any good option.

When you select `480p` you are only able to export as a `.mov` file.

Use `Save` rather than `Export`, which will allow you to re-save as a `.mp4`.

[image: Export As is NOT good]

Comment: I mentioned in the original post that I am aware that QuickTime X can trim this, but it's not what I'm looking for. Imagine that I have a 10 minute video and want to remove minutes 2, 4, and 6. In QuickTime 7 I could easily edit out those time-stamps and then save the file again, but QuickTime X cannot do that unless you split the video into separate parts, which is not what I want.

Comment: @TJLuoma yeah I understand the desire for "trim from the middle" functionality. But it is nice to know that QuickTime X can be used to re-save *some* cuts using the original encoding. Everything I had seen involved exporting as `.mov`.

Comment: Thanks so much for confirming this works.  Obviously it's not so fun to have separate clips, but until I saw this post I couldn't even find confirmation it was possible to resave clips as `.mp4`.

Comment: Important note that if you cut off the _beginning_ of a video in Quicktime X, some amount of the video before your cut point will be retained if the file is played in a non-Apple player. I am pretty sure this is done due to technical restrictions; you can't cut the beginning of an h264 video at non-keyframes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is allowed and wanted to mention our product, [nessViewer](https://www.nessviewer.com), which have the feature you requested.

Please note that we are the distributer of this application - it is commercial and costs 19.90 Euro.

The video editing is very near to the old style - which means that you select the start point, via shift pressed the end point, and then remove the selected video frames. This works on any part of the video and multiple times.

Beside this simple editing, the application allows it to join multiple videos (copy & paste does not work), rotate and flip, and to change the size of the video (e.g. to fade out black beams on top and below).

The application is signed, and certified by Apple (notarization). We have tested it on macOS 10.15 (Catalina) and have not found any problem so far.

One last info: this application is a collection of many features - not just video playback and editing. So at the beginning, it might need some time to learn how to handle all these features. If you need any help, please do not hesitate to contact us.

Comment: Can it make these edits without re-encoding, as specified in the question? It's not clear from your website.

Comment: I downloaded this app and could not figure it out. At all. it’s not at all like QuickTime 7 IMO.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to Rotate a `.mp4` via QuickTime Player 10.5, it marks the video as `Untitled` and forces me to "Export As:" a `.mov` HEVC or H.264 file.

But lossless / no-re-encoding Rotation edits can still be done via the `Rotate Left` and `Rotate Right` Finder Quick Actions, available in either the Right Click menu or Finder sidebar. The rotated video will save in-place.

[image]