# Simply Trimming MP4 Videos On Mac

Tags: mac, video, video-editing, mp4

So I have a simple task that I do a lot: trimming a video's head and tail off. On Windows, I open the photo, click edit, drag the bars to where I would like to cut, and I save. It will save as mp4 and I can overwrite the video by selecting the original video before saving (giving the new video the same name). However, on mac, it's not so easy.

Method 1: Quicktime -- Open the MP4 video in Quicktime, trim it using an ios-like interface, and save the video as a MOV (no option to overwrite or to save as MP4). Import this MOV into Premiere Rush (which takes a long time to launch and is slow), tell premiere to export to mp4, and wait a minute. Then delete the original mp4 and the mov, and I've finally got the trimmed mp4.

Method 2: VLC -- https://www.videoproc.com/troubleshoot-vlc/cut-or-trim-video-in-vlc-on-mac.htm It's clunky, but faster than Quicktime and better suited to my needs. One downside is that I cant tweak the start point once I start recording, I cant see ahead and if it goes too far ill have to trim it a second time, and there are pauses at the beginning and end.

Method 3: iMovie -- this is my go-to method for splicing clips together and complex trimming (removing segments in the middle). However, it's slow to export and about as slow as the Quicktime method.

I after researching, I could not find one app that trims as easily as Windows Video Player. I am asking the community if there is a simple, Quicktime-like video trimmer for mac that exports in MP4 instead of MOV. I am working with files that are usually 2-3 GB and therefore try to stay away from online services as much as possible (hence why I don't use cloud convert for mov to mp4).

Edit: It needs to be free.

**Solution:** along with losslesscut specified in the answer below, another solution is the Quick Look function. I'm not 100% sure if this is lossless, but if you want to simply trim video Quick Look has a simple video trimmer that allows you to replace existing video or create a new video in the original format. It is quite fast, making me think it is lossless.

Comment: Please don’t add answers to the question itself.

Comment: @nohillside how do I add my new solution for others who may benefit from it? Do I make a new Q/A (self-answered) question?

Comment: The LosslesCut solution is already posted below, the QuickTime solution would make a good answer on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117306/what-options-are-available-to-losslessly-trim-mp4-m4v-video-in-macos

Comment: @nohillside do you mean my QuickLook answer? And I don't think Quick Look is lossless, its just quick.

Comment: If it's quick is most likely lossless

Comment: The free and open source **Avidemux** - fixounet.free.fr/avidemux - is the perfect tool for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LosslessCut is free and meets these criteria.

You can download it here:

https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/releases

I recommend choosing the **LosslessCut-mac.pkg** file from the latest version available.

One thing to note is that mp4s cannot be cut *anywhere* but there are “key frames” which are where cuts can be done. Otherwise you risk audio/video being out of sync.

Comment: That's perfect! I love it!

Comment: @anonymous this is literally the [second answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259323/24324) of the [duplicate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/117306/24324). Please, pretty please, look a bit further the next time. It will help you (you'll get an answer quicker) and it will keep this site organised and maintainable.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke oh, sorry.

Comment: Ironically, I'm the person who asked the duplicate question :-)